# GRPC not working when I use 2 computers instead of 1

Tags: python, grpc

I have written the following code to transfer a video from client to server and then to transfer a stream of ints from server to client. It works when I make the server and client in 2 different terminals on one computer. But I get the following error when i do the same on 2 different computers.

```
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, Connect Failed)>
```

I'm simply setting up all these files on 2 different computers. On one computer, I call `python imageTest_client.py` and on the other `python imageTest_server.py`
What else has to be done to send messages from one computer to another?

**client.py**

```
import grpc
...


def run():
  channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50051')
  stub = imageTest_pb2_grpc.ImageTestStub(channel)
  for response in stub.Analyse( generateRequests() ):
      print(str(response.reply))
```

**server.py**

```
import grpc

class Greeter(imageTest_pb2_grpc.ImageTestServicer):

def Analyse(self, request_iterator, context):  
for req in request_iterator:
    yield imageTest_pb2.MsgReply(reply = 1 )



def serve():
   server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
   imageTest_pb2_grpc.add_ImageTestServicer_to_server(Greeter(), server)
   server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')
   server.start()
   try:
   while True:
       time.sleep(_ONE_DAY_IN_SECONDS)
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
       server.stop(0)
```

**.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option objc_class_prefix = "HLW";


// The greeting service definition.
service ImageTest {
 // Sends a greeting
 rpc Analyse (stream MsgRequest) returns (stream MsgReply) {}
}

// The request message containing the image.
message MsgRequest {
  bytes img = 1;
}

// The response message containing the reply 
message MsgReply {
int32 reply = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost` in your bind address. `localhost` is not exposed over the network.

Edit: Sorry, I confused your client with your server. Your server looks fine, but your client connects to `localhost`. There is no server there. You need to pass the IP address of the server in your client code.